# Why is Xcode giving me code verification fail warning when archiving application for distribution?

Tags: ios, xcode, distribution, adhoc

In the iOs dev portal I have:

- Created a distribution certificate
- Created an app id with unique bundle id
- Created a distribution provisioning profile using the certificate and
  app id

In the xcode project I have:

- set the correct bundle ID
- changed the release code signing to the distribution profile I
  created in the portal

When I build and archive I get the following warning and the archive does not show up in Organizer:

> 2011-08-23 13:45:28.417 Validation[25432:607] *** Warning: Defaulting
>   to the standard codesign tool warning: Application failed codesign
>   verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an
>   Apple submission certificate. (-19011)
>   /Users/sabobin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Playlist_Sequencer-hkzrncwdptzbvwbceggardugetvd/ArchiveIntermediates/MusicPlaylist/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/Playlist
>   Sequencer.app: valid on disk
>   /Users/sabobin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Playlist_Sequencer-hkzrncwdptzbvwbceggardugetvd/ArchiveIntermediates/MusicPlaylist/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/Playlist
>   Sequencer.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement test-requirement:
>   failed to satisfy code requirement(s)
>    - (null)

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score -1):

See my answer in this post.

[How to use device instead of Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075704/how-to-use-device-instead-of-simulator/7080948#7080948)

It may not fix your problem directly, but should help you get the code signing squared away and allow you to archive your app.