# How to setup iOS development environment?

Tags: iphone, ios, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use device instead of Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075704/how-to-use-device-instead-of-simulator)

I like to know how to test my own iOS app on my ipad or iphone. I know that there's IOS emulator in Mac OS, but I like to test my apps with a real hardware.

My research says that I have to jailbreak my ipad. Is this correct? or is there any other alternatives?

Comment: Are you a member of the ios developer program?

Comment: Its not **emulator**, it is **simulator**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075704/how-to-use-device-instead-of-simulator

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to jail break your device to test on it.

You do need to sign-up with apple and get a developer account.  That will allow you to get a provisioning profile and certs, then you can run on your device to test.

If you want others to test your apps on real devices look into ad-hoc deployments.

The majority of your development will be with the simulator but by all means, always test on real devices ...