# Test Flight Error: Invalid IPA: missing embedded provisioning profile - How do I fix this?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.2, testflight

I'm trying to package my app up and distribute an ad hoc version via Test Flight. I've already packaged and submitted the app to the app store so I'm trying to figure out which settings I need to change to make it work for ad hoc.

When I try to upload my .ipa in Test Flight I get "Invalid IPA: missing embedded provisioning profile"

I tried following the instructions from Test Flight here: http://support.testflightapp.com/kb/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4 But there isn't even in option of "Code Signing" for me in Xcode (v4.2).

I've created an ad hoc provisioning profile and downloaded it into Xcode.

I've changed the code signing identity in build settings (for both target and project) and after archive I've attached the ad hoc provisioning profile when sharing the .ipa.

I'm still getting the error. Any thoughts on what else I might need to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entitlements pane is now in project properties -> summary.

Answer (score 0):

I would try cleaning your app, and re-archive. Make sure that Xcode recognizes your AdHoc profile. It can be quite the pain in the ass to get Xcode to pick up your profile due to conflicts in your keychain. Open Organizer, select Provisioning Profiles, and make sure your AdHoc profile doesn't have any issues. If it does, you will probably need to clear out your keychain and profiles and start nice and clean. I have a post on SO that might help you. [Use Device Instead of Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075704/how-to-use-device-instead-of-simulator)

If you aren't having any issues with your profiles, try and just attach it after you upload your ipa file to TestFlight.

Comment: Thanks Bill, but none of that is working for me. I'm curious, I keep seeing the step where you create a new "Code Signing" file "entitlements.plist" as a part of the instructions (on TestFlight site and other places) but when I go file>new there isn't even an option to create a file type of "code signing." Do you have any ideas around why that might be? (FYI I've upgraded to Lion and Xcode 4.3 since originally posting - same issue persists).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still experiencing this error:

I was experiencing this issue with XCODE 4.3.

1 . Make sure you have a Ad-Hoc Cert :
[YouTube Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XVO0tIHmQTg)

1. After Archiving and Selecting the Distribute via Ad-Hoc option, Make sure that you **Update** your list of keys. The option is at the bottom of the list. And select the Ad-Hoc cert if you just had to create one.

i.e. Product > Archive > Distribute > "Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment" >
Next > Code Signing Identity ** Refresh Code Signing identity **

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on distributing your application via TestFlight you will need an Ad-Hoc provisioning profile generated through your Apple Developer account.
Every application I build has at least 2, often 3, different provisioning profiles assigned to them.

```
Development
Ad-Hoc for outside testing
Distribution
```